# FPDF Letter Spacing

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to set the letterspacing for a specific 'block' of text in fpdf. I have searched and have only found one way to set the letterspacing for the whole doc, and even that didn't work. The text is posted to the php fpdf generator.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','b',85, LetterSpacing Here?);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 8):

Based on other provided answers, I extended the FPDF class that we use so that underlining takes into account user-defined letter spacing.

```
<?php
class Custom_FPDF extends FPDF
{
protected $FontSpacingPt;      // current font spacing in points
protected $FontSpacing;        // current font spacing in user units

function SetFontSpacing($size)
{
    if($this->FontSpacingPt==$size)
        return;
    $this->FontSpacingPt = $size;
    $this->FontSpacing = $size/$this->k;
    if ($this->page>0)
        $this->_out(sprintf('BT %.3f Tc ET', $size));
}

protected function _dounderline($x, $y, $txt)
{
    // Underline text
    $up = $this->CurrentFont['up'];
    $ut = $this->CurrentFont['ut'];
    $w = $this->GetStringWidth($txt)+$this->ws*substr_count($txt,' ')+(strlen($txt)-1)*$this->FontSpacing;
    return sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F re f',$x*$this->k,($this->h-($y-$up/1000*$this->FontSize))*$this->k,$w*$this->k,-$ut/1000*$this->FontSizePt);
}
}
```

Sample use test:

```
$pdf = new Custom_FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'BU', 11);
$pdf->SetFontSpacing(3);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Test of letter spacing with underline', 0, 1);
$pdf->SetFontSpacing(0);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Test of letter spacing with underline');
$pdf->Output();
```

Tested extending FPDF version 1.81

Comment: It does the job pretty well but doesn't work perfectly with alignment (centered in my case)

Comment: @GDY in case you're still looking for a solution for centered text, you can give my answer a try.

Answer (score 4):

This will really allow you to do letter spacing:

```
// letter-spacing (0 for normal, 0.3 = 33%, 1 = 100%) 
function SetCharSpacing($cs) { 
    $this->_out(sprintf('BT %.3F Tc ET',$cs*$this->k)); 
}
```

Credits:
http://fpdf.de/forum/showthread.php?t=3241

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately **you can't do that** directly with only FPDF functions. What you need here is to code a new function wich recreate `Cell()` with some new parameters...

But wait... **someone already did that!**

It's here: [FPDF Add-On by Patrick Benny](http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/62/)

It's such a great job that you don't even need something else! :)

Comment: This works well if you need to fill the cell, but what if I just want 10% extra letter spacing? Designers/typographs often has special needs, that fpdf/fpdi doesn't solve.

Comment: @qualbeen late reply but you can use GetStringWidth to calculate the 'natural' width and then pass a 110% of that as the cell's desired width to CellFit(..) with force parameter set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Place it in your fpdf php class.

```
function SetFontSpacing( $size ) {
   if ( $this->FontSpacingPt == $size ) return;

   $this->FontSpacingPt = $size;
   $this->FontSpacing = $size / $this->k;

   if ( $this->page > 0 )
   $this->_out( sprintf( 'BT %.3f Tc ET', $size ) );
}
```

before that add global variable in fpdf class;
var $FontSpacingPt;

Hope it helps with lattest fpdf class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using these answers and having problems with right aligned text, I was able to fix it using the code below. I think it'll work for centered text too. The `GetStringWidth` function wasn't accounting for the new character spacing, so it was returning the wrong string width.

The part that fixes it is: `$wtf = $this->cs/4+1;` and `$w += $charw*$wtf;`. I don't know why this works, but after about an hour of trial and error and tinkering with different numbers and equations, those are the numbers that seem to work with any character spacing value. It may only work with my font (Roboto Condensed) so you may have to add or subtract from the `4` a bit to get it working with your font. I don't know.

If anyone is smarter than me and can add a real solution I'd really appreciate it. Or if it works perfectly for you I'd love to hear about it.

```
protected $cs; // character spacing

// Sets character spacing (0 for normal, 0.5 = 50%, 1 = 100%)
function SetFontSpacing($cs=0)
{
    $this->cs = $cs;
    $this->_out(sprintf('BT %.3F Tc ET', $cs*$this->k));
}

function GetStringWidth($s)
{
    // Get width of a string in the current font
    $s = (string)$s;
    $cw = &$this->CurrentFont['cw'];
    $w = 0;
    $l = strlen($s);
    for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++) {
        $charw = $cw[$s[$i]];
        $wtf = $this->cs/4+1;
        $w += $charw*$wtf;
    }
    return $w*$this->FontSize/1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PDF internally the character spacing will given in pt.

If you use the `$cs` parameter in this way, your `SetFontSpacing()` comments are incorrect.

> 0 means 0 pt, 0.5 means 0.5 units of your chosen unit specified in `AddPage()`.
> Also 0.5mm is 0.238pt == (0.5 * (72/25.4)).

The additional space required is calculated by:

```
(number of characters-1)*$this->cs.
```