# Increasing character space in FPDF fonts

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create PDF documents with PHP, and I'm using some fonts to stylize the text. It was working fine with some fonts, now I've set few more new fonts, I got spacing issue on all new fonts, characters are merging one into one, I need some more spacing between characters to make them clear and visible.
Can someone tell me how to set character spacing in FPDF, or is there any parameter in font.php files to change them manually because some other fonts are working fine?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FPDF Letter Spacing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126354/fpdf-letter-spacing)

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on google - first answer

[FPDF Letter Spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126354/fpdf-letter-spacing)

and direct link to the add-on you want

http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/62/

Hope that helps!